# using BehaviorSubject and not getting the value expected

Tags: angular, angular-components, behaviorsubject

I'm using a `service` globally and `BehaviorSubject` to share the `BehaviorSubject` property value in two components for now...
This is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobsService {
private partitionKeySource = new BehaviorSubject("not retrieved yet");

    partitionKey$ = this.partitionKeySource.asObservable();

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

  getJobs(): Observable<Job[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._jobsUrl).map((response: Response) => <Job>response.json())
   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    setPartitionKey(partitionKey: string) {
        this.partitionKeySource.next(partitionKey);


      }
}
```

This is the `JobsComponent`, I'm calling the `setPartitionKey()` method of my service and passing a value to it as a parameter from this component:

```
export class JobsComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit(): void {
this._jobsService.getJobs().subscribe((data: Job[]) => {//...some code})};
constructor(private _jobsService: JobsService, private router: Router) {}
select(partitionKey: string) {
        this._jobsService.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
        this._jobsService.partitionKey$.subscribe(response => {
            console.log('from jobs component the partitionKey value is: ' + response);
            console.log('after getting the response jobsComponent');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/job_details');
        }, error => console.log('there was an error: ' + error));
    }
```

This is the `JobsComponent html`:

```
<div class="jobContainer" *ngIf="isThereAnyJob === true">
    <div *ngFor="let job of jobs">
        <a (click)="select(job.PartitionKey)">{{job.Title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JobDetails component:

```
export class JobDetailsComponent{
constructor( private _jobsService: JobsService) {
        console.log('constructor called from JobDetails');
        this._jobsService.partitionKey$.subscribe(response => {
                console.log('from job details Component the partitionKey value is: ' + response);
            },
            error => console.log('there was an error from job details component: ' + error));
    }
```

I'm putting the JobsService globaly in the `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports://....
    declarations://....
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [Globals, JobsService, MissionService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So when I set the `partitionKeySource` value of my service I want to navigate to the `JobDetails` component to display the details of that job using the `partitionKey` value, I'm using global service and `BehaviorSubject` because I don't want to display the `partitionKey` value in the url...

When it navigates to `JobDetails` the value of `partitionKey` is the default one set on the `JobsService` instead of the `Job` `partitionKey` in particular...
I'm using `console.log()` to print the order and the partitionKey value of both components, which I want to be the same...

This is what is being printed:

```
from jobs component the partitionKey value is: 01f1f352-51e0-474e-962b-a75a56925342d 
after getting the response jobsComponent
constructor called from JobDetails
from job details Component the partitionKey value is: not retrieved yet
```

I want the partitionKey value to be the same in both components(`01f1f352-51e0-474e-962b-a75a56925342d`)... Why `JobDetails` is getting the default value if this is changed before using `JobsComponent`?

Comment: Are you adding `JobsService` to the providers of your component? Or only to the providers of AppModule

Comment: @LLai Only to the providers of AppModule...

Comment: From the order of your console log output, it seems like there are multiple instances of JobsService, but if it is only provided in AppModule there should not be. You could try moving the `.subscribe` in your JobDetails component from the constructor to the ngOnInit.

Comment: @LLai You are right, I'm so stubborn, when you asked me for the first time if I had `JobsService` added to my providers in my component I was sure it was only on my `AppModule` and I didn't look to my component, but now I looked and there is another `JobsService` in my component providers in `JobsComponent`, so that was the problem, I removed it and everything goes as I wish, sorry about that, if you elaborate the answer I'll choose it as the correct one, you deserve the point, thanks

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the order of the provided console log outputs, it looks like there are multiple instances of your service. Remove all instances of the `JobsService` from your Component providers and only keep it in the providers array of your AppModule

```
@Component({
    providers: [ JobsService ] // remove this
})
```

This will make JobsService a singleton service that can be shared across all components in the application.